# Does user flair automatically update?

Tags: discussion, flair

I know with this code you can display flair like the image below.

```
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com/users/4551041/hein">
    <img src="https://stackoverflow.com/users/flair/4551041.png" width="208" height="58" alt="profile for Hein at Stack Overflow, Q&amp;A for professional and enthusiast programmers" title="profile for Hein at Stack Overflow, Q&amp;A for professional and enthusiast programmers">
</a>
```

[image: profile for Hein at Stack Overflow, Q&A for professional and enthusiast programmers]

But I'm asking myself, do the reputation and number of badges change on the flair by themselves?